# Algorithm to find song by song name and artist name, match closest string

Tags: java, search

I'm using spotify's API to find a song based in a text Area with several song names - artist name, the challenge is that the information can be entered in several formats,
example:

```
Pink Floyd - shine on you crazy diamond
shine on you crazy diamond - pink Floyd
pink Floyd : shine on you crazy diamond
Pink Floyd - shine on you crazy diamond (HQ) (lyrics)
```

(And so on)

As a song can be unavailable in spotify I'd like to implement it in 2 ways based in user's choice: exact match, match if some percentage of the string find a match.

Any suggestion on how to implement this or algorithm that can help achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to have a look at the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It compares two strings by calculating the edit distance between them, i.e. the minimal number of edits (inserts, deletions or replacements of a character) that are necessary in order to turn the first string into the second one (or vice versa). It's a very basic and commonly used approach, however there are multiple other approaches for edit distances around that might fit your application's needs. Some of them are also mentioned in the article referenced above.